# 'ls' output doesn't show color anymore in macOS High Sierra

Tags: terminal, zsh, ls

I use `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`:

[image: my 'ls' result]

As shown in the screenshot `ls` is not showing color output anymore. I set color theme from iTerm2 and set zsh theme (wezm+ theme) from `oh-my-zsh`.

I try to set manually `LS_COLORS` but It also doesn't work. I guess the problem happens after deleting `zsh-templates-osx` due to update error using MacPorts. I also cannot find this issue on MacPorts website.

Is there any one who can help? I'm seriously thinking about reinstalling macOS and changing package managers to Homebrew.

Comment: On Ubuntu `ls` is an alias to `ls --color=auto` with the default installation.

Comment: AFH: Thanks for your comments. I'm seriously thinking about changing OS nexttime. But right now, I cannot afford to spend time to learn another OS and ecosystem (Keynote is the biggest tools for making money)

Comment: You can do the same in `~/.bashrc` on OSX, which solves your immediate problem.

Comment: AFH: Yes ! I tried to set 'ls --color=auto' to my .zshrc but it didn't work. Thank you ~~ ^^

Comment: JakeGould: Yes. I tried but it didn't work either. and all settings related to 'LS_Color' are already set in .oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh file. I also tried to set LS_COLOR variable on my .zshrc but it didn't work. Thank you for your comments ^^

Comment: @Giacomo1968 the `CLICOLOR` variable is only interpreted by the default macOS (BSD) version of `ls`, whereas `LS_COLOR` is only used by the GNU version, seems @dmaj7 is using the GNU version since it accepts a `--color` option. The var `LS_COLOR` doesn't enable colors though, it only defines the color scheme when colors are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -G
```

Make an alias of `ls` like `ll='ls -G'`

Comment: From man, `-G` stands for `--no-group`, where have you seen `-G` shows color?

Comment: @Toto: It applies to `ls` as found on BSD-heritage systems such as macOS - see https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ls